# TYPO3 Fluid Template Manager is using deprecated function

Tags: typo3, fluid

FTM is using setIgnoreEnableFields() which I mean is removed in TYPO3 6.2.

Fatal error: Call to a member function setIgnoreEnableFields() on a non-object in /typo3conf/ext/ftm/Classes/Domain/Repository/PagesRepository.php on line 75

Is there another function to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please mentioned next time that you already opened an issue report at http://forge.typo3.org/issues/57802

You can fix the extension manually (which is ok for a quick fix but not recommend for compatible issues)

Here is an example how to fix this:
https://review.typo3.org/#/c/14956/1/typo3/sysext/beuser/Classes/Domain/Repository/BackendUserRepository.php

Comment: Sorry, I'll remember that.

Now, when I click the Web -> Fluid Template Manager and the first-level page after I have created the Fluid Template, the Manager "window" with the tabs are completely empty. The manual says, that I need to regenerate the TYPOscript. But how do I do that when the window is empty?

Comment: I can't help you with Fluid Template Manager. I never used it, but I would look into the PHP error log first.